# How do you say "thank you" for work that is good for the community?

Tags: phrase-requests

I remember a Japanese student using a specific phrase for thanking a person for work for the good of the community - like cleaning up the common area of the dorm.  Seemed like and idiom.  Does anyone know the correct phrase?

Comment: It might be おつかれさまです。

Comment: I think you might be looking for お世話になりました。  This is a broad question, and I suspect this will be closed since there are probably several different things one might say in that situation. See: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/22352 Also See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: For your information before the question is closed, おつかれさまです is otsukaresama desu and お世話になりました is osewa ni narimashita.

Comment: Haven't been mentioned:
ごくろうさまです